# Lighttpd redirect and rewrite too many redirects

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I need to do redirect and rewrite for those cases above:

## First case

When user go to "http://my-website/jobs" the url to be resolved need to be "http://my-website/jobs.html"

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
  "/jobs$" => "/jobs.html"
)
```

## Second case

Then when user goes to "http://my-website/jobs.html" redirect to "http://my-website/jobs"

```
url.redirect = (
  "^/jobs.html$" => "/jobs"
)
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It seems like you're defining a redirect cycle. `/jobs` redirects to `/jobs.html` which redirects to `/jobs` which redirects to `/jobs.html`, repeat, repeat.. no?

Comment: @cody, i need to resolve the url to the html file and redirect with someone try to access the file directly. I need to keep the "beauty" version only. There is any way to do this?